# Querying a specific row of a group to create a new column

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to create a new column on a df copying one specific field that matches a condition between two columns.

Assuming this theoric df:

```
  V1 V2 V3
1  1 as  a
2  4 dc  a
3  3 ef  a
4  4 rg  b
5  6 yh  b
6  9 tg  b
```

I want to get the value of V2 when V1 equals 4 for each value of V3. And then replace that in a new column to get something like this:

```
  V1 V2 V3 result
1  1 as  a     dc
2  4 dc  a     dc
3  3 ef  a     dc
4  4 rg  b     rg
5  6 yh  b     rg
6  9 tg  b     rg
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can group by 'V3', get the corresponding value of 'V2', where 'V1 is 4

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
     group_by(V3) %>%
     mutate(result = V2[V1 == 4][1])
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   V3 [2]
#     V1 V2    V3    result
#  <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> 
#1     1 as    a     dc    
#2     4 dc    a     dc    
#3     3 ef    a     dc    
#4     4 rg    b     rg    
#5     6 yh    b     rg    
#6     9 tg    b     rg
```

If there are more than one match, select the first one

```
df1 %>%
     group_by(V3) %>%
     mutate(result = V2[match(4,  V1)])
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(V1 = c(1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 9L), V2 = c("as", "dc", 
"ef", "rg", "yh", "tg"), V3 = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b")),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Comment: Thanks, just a doubt whats the [1] use in the first code?

Comment: @Jhonathan If there are more than 1 instance of 4 for any group, after extracting the 'V2', `[1]`, will take the first instance instead of more than 1 to avoid getting any error with `mutate` (as mutate wants to return with  the same length as the original column length)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `data.table` approach:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, result := V2[match(4, V1)], V3]
```